# Prove: $\frac{1}{11\sqrt{2}} \leq \int_0^1 \frac{x^{10}}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx \leq \frac{1}{11}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, continuity

Prove: $\frac{1}{11\sqrt{2}} \leq \int_0^1 \frac{x^{10}}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx \leq \frac{1}{11}$

Hint: Use the (weighted) Mean Value Theorem for Integrals.

The MVT for Integrals:

Suppose that $u$ is continuous and $v$ is integrable and nonnegative on $[a,b]$

Then $\int_a^b u(x)v(x)dx=u(c)\int_b^a v(x)dx$

for some $c$ in $[a,b]$.

I plan on using $u(x)$ as $x^{10}$ as it is continuous and $v(x)$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ as it is integrable on [0,1]. I'm not sure how to go from there and find $c$.

Comment: [Second mean value?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals)

Comment: First mean value @BCLC

Comment: If you just swap your choice of $u$ and $v$, you will find that everything falls out nicely.

Comment: @TonyK What's the direct relevance of [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals) anyway? I think what's relevant is the [inequality in the proof of MVT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ7xB.png)

Comment: @angelo086 Oh I didn't know/forgot about [that MVT](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/29667daa22cdf8d9328e695ca5197293be5cdc83). Interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. One has, by a direct approach,
$$
\frac{x^{10}}{\sqrt{1+1}}\le \frac{x^{10}}{\sqrt{x+1}}\leq \frac{x^{10}}{\sqrt{0+1}}, \qquad 0\le x\le1.
$$

Comment: Short and elegant! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Choosing $v(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ doesn't work, I think:

I didn't use [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals) directly. I used something from the proof of MVT:

---

[image]

---

$$m \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}} dx \le \int_0^1 \frac{x^{10}}{\sqrt{x+1}} \le M \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}} dx$$

The best $m$ and $M$ I got are $0$ and $1$ resp as $0 \le x^{10} \le 1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$

---

So let's try

$u(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$

Now $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}} \le 1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$

So we have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^1 x^{10} dx \le \int_0^1 \frac{x^{10}}{\sqrt{x+1}} \le 1 \int_0^1 x^{10} dx$$

---

Remark: I think the 11's in the denominator may be a hint to use $u(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{10}}{\sqrt{1+x}}\,dx\leq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}x^{10}\,dx\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{10}\,dx}{1+x}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{11}\left(\log2-\frac{1627}{2520}\right)}$$
and by integration by parts
$$ I = \frac{1}{11 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{22}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{11}\,dx}{\sqrt{(1+x)^3}}\geq\frac{1}{11\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{528\sqrt{2}}$$
so we have the much better inequality
$$ \color{red}{0.065}621652\leq   I \leq \color{red}{0.065}721354.$$